# How can I install an older version of boto on an AWS instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, boto, revert

We have multiple Ubuntu instances on AWS EC2 with different versions of `boto` installed. One has 2.2.2, the other 2.8.0. One of our script behaves differently on the two machines, not working on the one with the older boto. I am trying to see if the version difference is the reason for it, or if there is something else going on. So what I want to do is to go back to 2.2.2 on the instance with 2.8.0 to test. How do I install an older version? I tried `sudo pip install -U boto 2.2.2` but it gave me `Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement 2.2.2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use virtualenv.  Create a new virtual environment on the instance with 2.8.0 and make sure that you tell virtualenv not to use the system-installed packages.  I'm pretty sure that is the default behavior but, just in case:

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages test_old_boto
```

Once the virtualenv is created:

```
$ cd test_old_boto
$ source bin/activate
```

and then install the old version of boto in the virtualenv:

```
$ pip install boto=2.2.2
```

and you should the be able to test things out.

Comment: But isn't `pip install boto=2.2.2` essentially the same as my `sudo pip install -U boto 2.2.2`? The message I got seems to suggest that `pip install` can't find the right package to download. How would running `virtualenv` help?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of the question.  I'm not sure why pip is unable to find 2.2.2 but you could just download the tarball from https://github.com/boto/boto/tree/2.2.2, untar it and then do a "python setup.py install".  I would still recommend using a virtualenv to keep this installation separated from your 2.8.0 install.

Answer (score 0):

as [Lisa Watanabe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2680525/lisa-watanabe) correctly answered and for whatever reason deleted, the correct syntax is `sudo pip install --upgrade boto==2.2.2` or `pip install --user --upgrade boto==2.2.2`